# NVIDIA GeForce Gt 630M for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I dualboot Ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8.1 pro. 
In Ubuntu, Software & updates > Additional Drivers i don't know what one should i choose and now i'm using x.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open  source).   Can i change to Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything you need works fine with the open-source driver, then you don't have to install the proprietary driver.

Or, if you're

- Using a laptop with hybrid-video config (Intel + nVidia).
- Want to reduce the power consumption by using the Intel GPU.

You can install the proprietary driver, which will allow you to choose which GPU to use (between ***Performance Mode*** and ***Power Saving Mode***).

Comment: Yes, i want to install proprietary driver but i don't know what one should i choose in Additional Drivers. now i use X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau ( open source ).

Comment: Other than that is ok, I think it's nvidia-331

Comment: i found 2 drivers [ NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.89 from vnidia-331 (open source)     and  NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331-updates ( proprietary) ].  i choose nvidia-331-updates (proprietary) > Apply Changes and close.  i open it again and see but driver isn't change.  why and how to change it?

Comment: You will need Internet connection to download the driver, after you hit "Apply Changes", it should start installing sequence. If not, try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates` in your terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t)